# Is it possible to initialize a String[] array and pass it in a method in 1 line?

Tags: java

Right now I have the following code:

```
String[] values = {str1, str2};
Utils.myMethod(values);
```

I would like to know if there is a way to do this all in one line. I've tried:

```
Utils.myMethod({str1, str2});
```

But that doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to specify the type of the array explicitly. It is not inferred. Hence the following is valid,

```
Utils.myMethod(new String[] {str1, str2});
```

Comment: ...and in case you want to work with Lists and want to initialize that list with values without much writing, use this:
Utils.myMethod(Arrays.asList(new String[] {str1, str2}));

Comment: You can make it simple further: Utils.myMethod(Arrays.asList(str1, str2)); (with Java 1.5 or above since it is a vararg method)

Comment: Damnit, that's what i meant. C+P from OP's post made my skill look horrible. I don't deserve to be called a Nerd. You'll find me outside.

Comment: @Marithmu it's a lot more verbose than that. here's the required code: `Utils.myMethod((String[]) Arrays.asList(str1, str2).toArray());`

Answer (score 4):

If you own the method in question, consider using the varargs syntax and declaring it like this:

```
void myMethod(String... args) {
```

Then, you can call it like this

```
Utils.myMethod(str1, str2);
```

Then let the compiler put the array together for you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always rewrite your method to use [varargs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html). This way, you could write

```
Utils.myMethod(str1, str2);
```